# Exception Handling between member functions of a class

Tags: exception, error-handling

Assume there are two member functions f1(), f2() of an object O2.
Consider below code.

O2::f2()
{

```
if(somestring.length()<20)
{
    throw
}
```

}

O2::f1()
{

```
try
{
    f2()
}
catch(...)
{
    //Some handling
}
```

}

Here ideally f1 should catch exception thrown by exception. But it is not happening. Instead,
getting error as shown below:

> Terminated without any active exception

Answer (score 0):

This is because f2 has an empty throw statement. If that statement is executed without an active exception being handled, terminate is supposed to be called.You need to throw something in order to catch

Comment: I tried throwing some int etc....although the behaviour is same

Comment: It is working. But what makes the difference bw throw  and throw <ex>. throw abnormally terminates, where as the second one handles exception.